# Import multiple ascii text files - add original file name to each data frame - format the required data

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I would like to import multiple ascii text files with selected rows in a one shot and I want to add file name as an ID number (variable) and then format the data as required (see the image below)

```
setwd("working_dir")
library(data.table)
library(WriteXLS)
files <- list.files(pattern=".*.asc")
file.list <- sapply(files, function(x)read.csv(x,header=F,skip = 10,nrows=10,stringsAsFactors=F), simplify=FALSE)
df1 <- rbindlist(file.list, idcol="id")[, id := substr(id,1,7)]
WriteXLS(df1,"all_1.xls",Encoding = "latin1")
```

### this is how df1 data frame looks like and i want to format/select only the required data as shown in my deired result picture

```
df1 <-structure(list(id = c("9864707", "9864707", "9864707", "9864707", 
"9864707", "9864707", "9864707", "9864707", "9864707", "9864707", 
"9864708", "9864708", "9864708", "9864708", "9864708", "9864708", 
"9864708", "9864708", "9864708", "9864708"), V1 = c("Mean irradiance (kW/m²)", 
"1.000", "Pmax", "267.793", "Module voltage", "Voc", "37.552", 
"Module current", "Isc", "9.217", "Mean irradiance (kW/m²)", 
"1.000", "Pmax", "268.211", "Module voltage", "Voc", "38.234", 
"Module current", "Isc", "9.181"), V2 = c("Cell efficiency (%)", 
"18.4", "Module temperature (°C)", "22.2", "", "Vmp", "31.159", 
"", "Imp", "8.735", "Cell efficiency (%)", "18.4", "Module temperature (°C)", 
"22.2", "", "Vmp", "31.208", "", "Imp", "8.735"), V3 = c("Module efficiency (%)", 
"16.4", "", "", "", "Series resistance", "0.1256", "", "Shunt resistance", 
"191.7", "Module efficiency (%)", "16.5", "", "", "", "Series resistance", 
"0.3718", "", "Shunt resistance", "309.8"), V4 = c("Fill factor (%)", 
"77.4", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Fill factor (%)", "76.4", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")), .Names = c("id", "V1", "V2", 
"V3", "V4"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000000000a7b0788>)
```

### my actual result looks like these

[image]

### my desired result

[image]

### below is the links of sample ascii text files. could anyone of you help me to get my desired result.

[sample file 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ke07dc2d7dup7z7/9864707.asc%7E?dl=0)
[sample file 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/khlctrpqqtizhsh/9864708.asc%7E?dl=0)

R session info
[image]

Comment: Links to dropbox and pictures of data are not particularly helpful. You should try to include a minimal [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in the question itself to make it clear what your issue is.

Comment: @MrFlick: Thank you for the suggestion. I updated the question. i provided the reproducibe data to get the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gross work-around, but it'll work...at least based off the info you provided.

```
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

# Reproducing the data frame
a <- data.frame(
  id = c("9864707", "9864707", "9864707", "9864707", 
         "9864707", "9864707", "9864707", "9864707", "9864707", "9864707", 
         "9864708", "9864708", "9864708", "9864708", "9864708", "9864708", 
         "9864708", "9864708", "9864708", "9864708"), 
  V1 = c("Mean irradiance (kW/m²)", 
         "1.000", "Pmax", "267.793", "Module voltage", "Voc", "37.552", 
         "Module current", "Isc", "9.217", "Mean irradiance (kW/m²)", 
         "1.000", "Pmax", "268.211", "Module voltage", "Voc", "38.234", 
         "Module current", "Isc", "9.181"), 
  V2 = c("Cell efficiency (%)", 
         "18.4", "Module temperature (°C)", "22.2", "", "Vmp", "31.159", 
         "", "Imp", "8.735", "Cell efficiency (%)", "18.4", 
         "Module temperature (°C)", 
         "22.2", "", "Vmp", "31.208", "", "Imp", "8.735"),
  V3 = c("Module efficiency (%)", 
         "16.4", "", "", "", "Series resistance", "0.1256", "", "Shunt resistance", 
         "191.7", "Module efficiency (%)", "16.5", "", "", "", "Series resistance", 
         "0.3718", "", "Shunt resistance", "309.8"), 
  V4 = c("Fill factor (%)", 
         "77.4", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Fill factor (%)", "76.4", 
         "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Splitting the data frame into a list of data frames where the id is the key value
b <- split(a, a$id)


# Loop over the list of data frames to apply a cleaning function
c <- lapply(b, function(i){
  # Remove the rows where there is only one identifier and no values; as these
  # are not columns and will result in an unbalanced vector of 14 names, to 12
  # values which we'll get to in a second.
  # 1) Filter the data frame where the cell in column V2 has no characters
  # 2) unlist the data frame to a character vector after removing the id column 
  aa <- i %>% filter(nchar(V2) > 0) %>% select(-id) %>% unlist %>% as.character

  # Remove empty characters
  bb <- aa[nchar(aa) > 0]
  # If we find a letter in the character; we know it's supposed to be a column name
  c_name <- bb[grepl("[A-z]",bb)]

  # Inversely; find the numerics
  d_val <- as.numeric(bb[!grepl("[A-z]",bb)])

  # Bind the numberic values nto a new data frame
  df <- as.data.frame(rbind(d_val),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  # name the columns with the names we extracted
  colnames(df) <- c_name

  # Get the unique id of the file (where we split above) and bind it into the
  # above created data frame
  df <- cbind(id = i[['id']][[1]], df)
  # drop the rownames
  row.names(df) <- NULL
  # return the data frame
  df
}) 

# Bind into one data.frame
d <- rbind.pages(c)


> str(d)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  13 variables:
#  $ id                     : chr  "9864707" "9864708"
# $ Mean irradiance (kW/m²): num  1 1
# $ Pmax                   : num  268 268
# $ Voc                    : num  37.6 38.2
# $ Isc                    : num  9.22 9.18
# $ Cell efficiency (%)    : num  18.4 18.4
# $ Module temperature (°C): num  22.2 22.2
# $ Vmp                    : num  31.2 31.2
# $ Imp                    : num  8.73 8.73
# $ Module efficiency (%)  : num  16.4 16.5
# $ Series resistance      : num  0.126 0.372
# $ Shunt resistance       : num  192 310
# $ Fill factor (%)        : num  77.4 76.4
```

Comment: "you are awesome". Thank you very much. your solution worked very well. The way you formated the data is awesome, i learned many new points. Thanks #R_GURU

Comment: @Chanti thanks for the nice words. I realized after the fact that you said you had multiple files. we're you able to amend the above into a loop that applied to all of them? just curious.

Comment: I tried with 6 ascii files and the loop worked well without any errors. In-case if i face any errors with large no of files, i will let you know. thank you once again.